# Как посчитать пользователей, попавших в две группы из двух?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Пробую решать разные задачки в качестве самообразования.

Есть DataFrame:

```
orders = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')
```

Он содержит столбцы:

```
print(orders.head())

   transaction_id  visitor_id        date  revenue group
0      3667963787  3312258926  2019-08-15     1650     B
1      2804400009  3642806036  2019-08-15      730     B
2      2961555356  4069496402  2019-08-15      400     A
3      3797467345  1196621759  2019-08-15     9759     B
4      2282983706  2322279887  2019-08-15     2308     B
```

- *transaction_id* — идентификатор заказа;
- *visitor_id* — идентификатор пользователя, совершившего заказ;
- *date* — дата, когда был совершён заказ;
- *revenue* — выручка заказа;
- *group* — группа A/B-теста, в которую попал заказ.

**Нужно проверить сколько пользователей попали одновременно в обе группы и затем удалить их из таблицы.**

Проблема начинается с поиска.

Попробовано:

- создание срезов по группам и их объединение. Не работает.
- группировка по 'visitor_id' и 'group' с поиском количества заказов. Но дальше с этой таблицей не получается что-либо сделать.

Затуп конкретный. Очень прошу помочь. Для меня это в новинку.

**Спасибо.**

Answer (score 3):

После того как вы сделали группировку по 'visitor_id' и 'group', вы можете добавить соответствующую колонку в датафрейм и затем отобрать по этому признаку.
Покажу на следующем примере

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,'A'], [1, 'B'], [2, 'A'], [2, 'B'], [3, 'A'], [4, 'B']], columns=['id','c'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь группируем, как это делали вы

```
countGroups = df.groupby('id')['c'].nunique()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мерджим, обратите внимание, что это повлияло на названия колонок

```
df = df.merge(countGroups, on=["id", "id"])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь мы делаем обратную операцию, мы не удаляем, а выбираем те колонки, которые нам нужны по условию

```
df[df['c_y'] == 1]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вас в образовательных целях интересует как именно удалять по условию, то похожий ответ нашла [тут](https://coderoad.ru/48703279/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-dtypes-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8), однако мне показалось, что подход выше проще.

При необходимости можно будет удалить лишний столбец и переименовать колонки.

Answer (score 2):

С двумя группами это сделать довольно просто. Если у вас есть датафрейм `df`, например:

```
   id group
0   1     a
1   2     a
2   3     b
3   3     a
4   2     b
5   1     a
```

то сделать можно так:

```
mask = df.loc[df["group"]=="a", "id"].isin(df.loc[df["group"]=="b", "id"])
res = df.drop(mask[mask].index)
```

тогда `res` будет:

```
   id group
0   1     a
2   3     b
4   2     b
5   1     a
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверить, сколько пользователей попали одновременно в обе группы можно так:

```
orders.groupby('visitor_id').agg({'group' : 'nunique'}).query('group>1').count()
```

Далее создаем список пользователей с уникальными visitor_id:

```
double_users = orders.groupby('visitor_id').agg({'group' : 'nunique'})
.reset_index().query('group>1')['visitor_id'].unique()
```

И удаляем этих пользователей из таблицы orders:

```
orders = orders.query('visitor_id not in @double_users')
```